# Show message box in userform under specific condition

Tags: excel, vba

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aZd59.jpg)I have sheet1  contains 3 columns item,brand, quantity  and userform  contains the same element in sheet1  with textbox1, 2, 3 I would code do when I write the data in userform  show me warning message "you can't add this brand  only 3 or 4...etc available".

For more explaining showing message depends on textbox3  example 
column 3 in sheet1 contains quantity and when i fill textbox3 more than column 3 then show the message.

Answer (score -1):

I'm still not entirely sure what you mean, but try something like this

```
Private Sub TextBox1_AfterUpdate()

'assuming this is the range where the relevant values are'
MaxValu = Application.WorksheetFunction.max(Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C3:C5"))

'change the text box value to an integer'
TxtBoxValu = CInt(Me.TextBox1.Value)

If TxtBoxValu > MaxValu Then MsgBox "this value is too high, the maximum you can 
pick is " & MaxValu 


End Sub
```

Comment: i attached my file   above  maybe you understand me

Comment: do you want the msgbox to say "please choose 300,200 or 100?"

Comment: I'm still not entirely clear what you need, but are the acceptable answers in a specific place on a specific sheet? e.g. Sheets("ASheetName").Range("A1:A3")

Comment: do you see my image above? ok  i have sheet1 contains  column 3 a,b,c  (item,brand, quantity) and userform textbox1,2,3 when i  fill in user form  transfer data to sheet to but when i write the quantity more than what contains in column 3 (c) the balnce then show the message  you excessed  the quantity   for example the balance of  brand in column 3  300q when i fill textbox3 in userform  400q  as you see it more than what contains in sheet in column 3 here i would show the message " you can't add this quantity available  only300

Comment: you have wrong in this line                 pick is " & MaxValu